# How to compile EJB 2.0 programs for Glassfish without IDE?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am using Sun Glassfish Enterprise Server 9.1. How can I compile EJB 2.0 programs without using any IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Just the usual way with [JDK](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk6.jsp). You at least need to take Glassfish' libraries in the `-cp` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)